# How to stop from.show() displaying multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that reads though a group of documents and displays a new form is a certain value is found. MY issue here is that all though the application is reading the files and is displaying how I would like I am getting multiple forms drawn  as the application is just reading thought the directory.

[image]

What I am unable to find is how to stop this from moving onto the next file before the first form has been closed. I tried `.ShowDialog()` but this does not work with what I am trying.

My current code is as follow's:

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
{
    current++;
    fileProcessBar.Value = current / count * 60 + 40;                 

    string[] alllines = File.ReadAllLines(fi.FullName);

    CreateForm CF = new CreateForm(fi.FullName);


    for (int i = 0; i < alllines.Length; i++)
    {

        if (alllines[i].Contains("$"))
        {
            // prompt
            int dollarIndex = alllines[i].IndexOf("--");
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(--.{1,100})");
            var chars = regex.Match(alllines[i]).ToString();

            string PromptText = chars.Replace("-", "");

            CF.AddToCanvas(PromptText);
            CF.Show();                                                                
        }

    }
}
```

I thought maybe adding another `foreach` loop but would not account for `form2` close

Comment: show it modal so you have to close the window before the code continues?

Comment: `I tried .ShowDialog() but this does not work with what I am trying.` how does it "not work"

Comment: @BugFinder, that is correct I am wanting it so you have to close the window before it populates another, the issue is if I use `showDialog` this does populate the dialog box with all the relevant information meaning you end up with a vast amount of windows

Comment: @BugFinder's suggestion would mean that reading wouldn't continue until the window was closed; e.g. if you've got 100 files and find a match in file 3 file 4 won't be read until the window is closed - each match will result in the same behaviour. Is this what you want? Approaches like this are good if you need to confirm something. However, if it's more of a summary it might be better to update the window with each file or leave displaying it until the end and display a summary - maybe writing the full results to a file?

Comment: @Gareth, a condition of the application is that the results of the file would need to be displayed (Unless there is no values that need updating), if I add `ShowDialog` outside of the for loop I can see how this would be better however I get a blank window for each document that does not need updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you merely want to open one form per-file and block until that form is closed. Then in that case try

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
{
    current++;
    fileProcessBar.Value = current / count * 60 + 40;                 
    string[] alllines = File.ReadAllLines(fi.FullName);

    // Ensure that resources are released.
    using (CreateForm CF = new CreateForm(fi.FullName))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < alllines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (alllines[i].Contains("$"))
            {
                int dollarIndex = alllines[i].IndexOf("--");
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"(--.{1,100})");
                var chars = regex.Match(alllines[i]).ToString();
                string PromptText = chars.Replace("-", "");

                CF.AddToCanvas(PromptText);
                CF.ShowDialog(); // This should block until closed.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.